# Update a textbox from a php/myswl dynamically created select box

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, textbox, drop-down-menu

So I am trying to get a group of text boxes to display the information current to the select box which is dynamically created from a PHP MySQL request. The select generates fine, but only populates the last line of the table. I want to make it so that when you change the select box the text boxes update to reflect the new information.

Current code to get the information from MySQL:

```
  <div id="edithidden" style="display:none;">
        <div id="prompt"><strong>Section to Edit:</strong></div>
        <div id="answer">
        <form id="editorginfo" action="" method="post">
            <select id="edit">
                <option>Section to Edit</option>
                <?php
$query = $db->query("SELECT ID, OrgName, Phone, Location FROM emergencyorg");

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$pid=$row['ID'];
$name=$row['OrgName'];
$phone=$row['Phone'];
$loc=$row['Location'];

        echo "<option value='" . $pid . "' ";
        if($row['OrgName']==$pid){
        echo ' selected';
        }
        echo">" . $name . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
        </div>          
        <div id="prompt">Organization Name:</div>
    <div id="answer">
        <input type="text" name="editorgname" id="editorgname" value="<?=$name?>"/>
    </div>
    <div id="prompt">Organization Phone Number:</div>
    <div id="answer">
        <input type="text" name="editorgphone" id="editorgphone" value="<?=$phone?>"/>
    </div>
    <div id="prompt">Orginization Location:</div>
    <div id="answer">
        <input type="text" name="editorglocation" id="editorglocation" value="<?=$loc?>"/>
    </div>
    <div id="prompt">
        <input type="submit" id="editorg" name="editorg" value="Update Information" />
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Does this have to be done with AJAX?

Thanks again in advance!

Comment: You have to use AJAX for this.

Comment: If You want to update the text box dynamically without page refresh then you have to go for ajax.

Comment: you mean mysql, not myswl, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ajax is probably your best bet.

But if you don't want to do that (maybe keeping hits on the server to a minimum is important), then you could load all the data for every organization into hidden fields (use the ID of the organization as a prefix to distinguish between different organizations) and then use javascript to load data into the fields in the onchange event of the `<select>`

Perhaps something like this (untested semi-pseudo code using jQuery)

```
<select onchange="changeOrg(this);">
<option value='1'>My org</option>
.
.
.
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="1_org_address" id="1_org_address" value="12 Nowhere St" />
.
.
.

<label>Address</label><br />
<input type="text" name="org_address" id="org_address" />

<script>
function changeOrg(org){
var chosen_org_id = $(org).val()
 $("#org_address").val($("#" + chosen_org_id + "_org_address").val());
//etc
}
</script>
```

Comment: so with this method the rest of the array would have to be output to hidden fields correct?

Comment: Yes, the dots indicate "more of the same kind of thing goes here"

Comment: Not sure how I would format the PHP to output remaining parts of the array to the hidden code though. Maybe I'm just too tired to tackle this tonight lol.

Comment: Yeah, you couldn't directly output the hidden fields at the same time as the select options. But you could concatenate a string with hidden field HTML in it, and then print out that string after you've finished looping through the select options.

Ugly. The AJAX approach would require a bit more skill but would probably be more elegant, readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use javascript to do this. There are 2 ways:

1) Save your PHP data to a javascript object, and add a change event on the select, which depending on the selected option, goes in the javascript object to find the new inputs' values

or

2) Add a change event on the select to do an AJAX request and refresh the inputs' values

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid page reloading, then ajax is the way to go. You can use the jQuery `$.post` method to do this. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Here's a sample code:

```
$('#select').change(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  $.post('data_source.php', {'select_value' : val}, 
    function(response){
       $('#table').html(response);
    }
  );
});
```

But if you're input is already in the database, maybe you can just load them right away and just hide and show things when the value of the select box changes.

Comment: ok, then in the php file throw something like this in?

    <?php
include_once "connect.php";
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM emergencyorg WHERE ID = val");
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$orgname = $row['OrgName'];
$phone = $row['Phone'];
$loc = $row['Location'];
}
 ?>

Comment: yes, if you're working with tables(also put the table tags in there) but if you want to update the value of some textboxes then you have to use ```json_encode``` in your server like this: ```json_encode($array_that_stores_your_data);``` then use ```JSON.parse(response)``` later on in javascript to convert your data to a javascript object which you can then loop through using ```for in``` or ```for``` loop. I hope that made sense.
And by the way you could use 3 backticks to wrap your code if you're posting a code in the comments to make things readable for people.

Comment: yes ```json_encode``` is a php function. I assume you already know how to fill an array with data from the database so this would be easy.